# PHP - TCP client using fgets to get data/chat from the server doesnt work

Tags: php, tcp, client

to begin with the fputs works for sending chat from the PHP site to this gaming server. But when I use fgets to get all the chatlogs from the server it doesnt return it, bascially for example when I write something in the textfield and send it using the button in the following code, it sends message to the server, I want it to return that value back from the server, or get all the chatlogs from the server and put it into the client which is a php website, here is the code:

```
 <?php

 $host="192.168.0.6";
 $port = 7777;
 // open a client connection
 $fp = fsockopen ($host, $port, $errno, $timeout);
 if (!$fp){
 $result = "Error: could not open socket connection";
 }
 else
 {

  echo '<center><form action="tcpclient.php "method="POST" /></center>';
  echo '<center>'."Nickname: ".'<input type="text" name="nick" size="31" /></center>';
  echo '<center>'." Text: ".'<input type="text" name="chat" size="150" /> <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send"  /></center>';

  if (isSet($_POST['send'])) $formvalue =$_POST['chat'];
  //$name = $_POST['nick'];
  //if (isSet($_POST['send'])) $formvalue + $_POST['chat']; 
  fputs ($fp, $formvalue);

  }
  $result = fgets ($fp, 7777);
  echo $result;

  ?>
```

Comment: @GungFoo sorry, but that's just BS. PHP has full support for sockets (not just tcp), libevent and everything else one might need. And yeah, it also doesn't leak for a few years now. Got more prejudice to show?

Comment: if websites are nails and socket programming screws, then php is a hammer. Are you always trying to hammer in screws? It might be "easy" to write socket handling functions in PHP but it has nothing to do with efficiency, nor with my prejudice. Also why feel offended? this is technical, not personal. PS: look at Mirwais Maarij comment to one of the answers: "But it lags".. See my point? :)

Comment: "But it lags" because he calls a blocking method that doesn't return. It has nothing to do with performance. PHP is just as slow and hungry as Python, Ruby or Perl i.e. good enough for everyday tasks. Comparing it to C would be stupid, no?

Comment: imo PHP makes an exceptional job at being hungry and not giving up memory once it has eaten it. I am a proponent of the "right tool for the right job" philosophy.. and PHP means P-retty H-omeP-ages. Not comparing tools before hammering in a screw with a hammer saying: "but the hammer fully supports it" is stupid, no?

Comment: ..chances are there is a TCP client, probably even written in C, for whatever kind of protocol Mirwais Maarij wants to use. Even if that's just nc.. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fgets()` only reads one line (terminated by `"\n"`) and will block until `"\n"` is received or the connection is closed. Make sure one of these things happens. (Use `telnet` or `nc` programs)

Oh and I'm not sure, but it might be expecting `"\r\n"` on Windows, and won't react to `"\n"` alone. Don't take my word on it though.

If there is no newline, use `fread` and a combination of `stream_select` and `stream_set_blocking` (refer to the manual).

If it's anything even more complex, you might want to switch to `socket_*` functions. Note that sockets and streams don't mix.

---

Sorry, I'm too lazy for an example. You can look [here](https://bitbucket.org/virtulis/22sync/src/3ba8c834d507/22sync.php) for a general example of `stream_select` in action (disclaimer: the code is ugly, I know.)

Basically, you'd `stream_set_blocking` to 0 and loop with `stream_select` and `fread` until you've read everything (if you can detect that) or hit a timeout. It's hard to suggest anything not knowing the protocol.

Comment: could you perhaps construct an example code which I could look at to get an idea please, I get what you mean tho and willing to use fread and stream_select..

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually implement the protocol the server speaks. When you call `fgets`, you just get whatever data the TCP stack happens to have ready at that time, which is definitely not what you want.

Comment: But it lags when I try to refresh the php site and it times out. 

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded.
I got this error after adding fgets into my lines of code

Comment: Did you actually implement the protocol that the server speaks? If not, you shouldn't expect it to work.